# can't paste into Jshell Version 11.0.11 reproduced on two machines

Tags: terminal, java, clipboard

I have a rather strange problem on two of my notebooks one running Manjaro Linux (Arch for children) and the other Ubuntu 20.10. When I use **Jshell** the read-eval-print loop tool for **Java 11**, ***I can't paste into Jshell***, not with the mouse and not with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> I made a little video demonstrating the problem.

It only happens in Jshell, normal bash isn't affected. (`echo` command at the beginning of the first video works fine)

https://www.mediafire.com/file/xjy9i8np16zfuit/Peek+2021-06-15+18-03.mp4/file (under 1 MB big)

I made another recording that shows that in ether xfce4 terminal or st terminal after pasting a string of characters into jshell it freezes, until typing 17 characters into the seemingly frozen jshell, when the pasted text appears plus the typed in characters after the freeze. (if i use letters instead of numbers like in the video the output looks like this:

```
jshell> System.out.println("This is a Test...")abcdefghijklmnopqrs
in both st and xfce4 terminal
```

https://www.mediafire.com/file/m2asx0y5tatnj89/Peek+2021-06-15+18-36.mp4/file (1.3 MB)

Used Java Version on both machines is:

```
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

If this should be a question for a Java board, could you point one out to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be due to the issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242919

```
Trying to paste to jshell causes a deadlock.
```

This was fixed in Java 15 a while ago, but only recently backported to 11u (should be fixed in 11.0.12)

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this on Java 11.0.11. Fixed in newer 11.0.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use

OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_11.0.10_9

until there is a new build with the fix noted by @Jorn